# Temporarily Disable a DIV while setInterval is running

Tags: javascript, setinterval, disabled-control

I want to disable some part of my html while Im running `setInterval` and make it back again after the setInterval is complete.

[How is it?](http://jsfiddle.net/C7dMy/1/)

```
<div id="on">CLICK THIS : <span id="status">ENABLED</span></div>
<button id="run">LOAD</button

$('#run').on('click', function () {
    var i = 0;
    var go = setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        $('#run').html('Loading ' + i + ' or 10...');
        $('#status').html('DISABLED');
        $('#on').unbind('click keyup keypress keydown');
        if (i === 10) {
            clearInterval(go);
            $('#status').html('ENABLED');
            $('#run').html('DONE');
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$('#on').on('click', function () {
    $('#status').html('CLICKING');
});
```

Here, what i want to achieve is that when i click the `Loading Button` the `Click This` should not accept any click event until the loading is DONE. But click is still triggered. Is there any other way to do this?

**[And i dont want to use disabled="disabled"]**

Comment: then you need to do the unbind on the element not on document

Comment: sorry, i just update the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want a click event to trigger a callback unbind the event or set a flag that is checked in the callback. Also you are doing the unbind within the callback, so event will not be unbound till it is called for the first time

```
$('#run').on('click', function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('#status').html('DISABLED');
    $("#on").unbind('click keyup keypress keydown');
    var go = setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        $('#run').html('Loading ' + i + ' or 10...');
        if (i === 10) {
            clearInterval(go);
            $('#status').html('ENABLED');
            $('#run').html('DONE');
            $("#on").on("click",onDivClicked);
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$('#on').on('click', onDivClicked);

function onDivClicked(){
    $('#status').html('CLICKING');
}
```

Or setting a flag

```
$('#on').data("active",true);
$('#run').on('click', function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('#status').html('DISABLED');
    $("#on").data("active",false);
    var go = setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        $('#run').html('Loading ' + i + ' or 10...');
        if (i === 10) {
            clearInterval(go);
            $('#status').html('ENABLED');
            $('#run').html('DONE');
            $("#on").data("active",true);
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$('#on').on('click', function () {
    if(!$(this).data("active")) return;
    $('#status').html('CLICKING');
});
```

Comment: im not js pro. may i know what return; means? is it returning false?

Comment: it's returning nothing, it is just telling the function to exit now

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7dMy/3/)

```
$('#run').on('click', function () {
    var i = 0;
    var go = setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        $('#on').attr("running","true");
        $('#run').html('Loading ' + i + ' or 10...');
        $('#status').html('DISABLED');
        if (i === 10) {
            clearInterval(go);
            $('#status').html('ENABLED');
            $('#run').html('DONE');
            $('#on').removeAttr("running");
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$('#on').on('click', function () {
    var running = $(this).attr('running');

    if (typeof running !== typeof undefined && running !== false) {

    }
    else{
       $('#status').html('CLICKING');
    }
});
```

Comment: you are setting the attribute within the setInterval callback, the event will still be active until the first interval is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
    function foo(){
        var i = 0;
        $('#on').off('click', foo);
        var go = setInterval(function () {
            i++;
            $('#run').html('Loading ' + i + ' or 10...');
            $('#status').html('DISABLED');
            $(document).unbind('click keyup keypress keydown');
            if (i === 10) {
                clearInterval(go);
                $('#on').on('click', foo);
                $('#status').html('ENABLED');
                $('#run').html('DONE');      
            }
        }

    $('#on').on('click', foo);
```